# Any rational explanation or just coincidence? Upvote of visited question

Tags: discussion, up-votes

I was just browsing some of my top answers on SO. I visited [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505461/function-returning-pointer-to-itself/6505517#6505517), edited the question (there was a typo), and my answer to that question got upvoted in 5 seconds. The question(and my answer) are at least 2 weeks old and not that popular (~500 views).

***So is that a coincidence? Or editing a post may have triggered an event which might have attracted someone's attention to the post?*** I am inclined to reject the idea that the question poster voted me up because he was last seen 2 hours ago...

This example is vivid, but I sometimes get the impression that it is common do get an upvote to an old question or answer which you've recently visited/edited.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Editing posts can bring them up on the front page. Someone browsing at that time could have seen that question and liked your answer.

Comment: ***Can*** bring them or ***does*** bring them?

Comment: It *will* bring them to the default front page, which is sorted by the latest activity - and editing is considered activity same way as adding answer, setting bounty or accepting an answer.

Comment: @Armen: Given the outwardly nondeterministic manner in which everyone's individual "front page" is generated, "can" is as good as it gets.

Comment: It's complex (i.e. not _just_ based on recent activity), but essentially yes. [It does.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/)

Comment: It definitely *does* bump them. That doesn't guarantee that they'll appear on *your* front page, but if someone monitors the `[c++]` tag and you edit a post on a question with that tag, it's *quite* likely that they'll see it on their homepage. This is by far the most likely scenario; there's no bug in the system that allows you to upvote your own answer by editing it.

Comment: @Cody: I never thought ***I*** upvoted it :)